# Searching for a Regex to disable any "/" before the first letter

Tags: regex

I am actually got an Angular form which upload some files on a cloud, but those files could be in directories with subdirectories like

> "directory/subdirectory/filename"

My form had some inputs, and I added a ng-pattern on a text input.

I can't accept sentence with `"/"` at first character like

> /directory/subdirectory/filename

I am searching for a regex to deny any `"/"` until the first letter of a directory name.

So, correct way is:

> directory/blabla;

and wrong way is:

> /directory/blabla;

I tried `[^/]*` but it is detect all the `'/'` in my sentence.

Any idea please ?

Comment: Can you add the question in more detail please?

Comment: yep sorry, i just edited it :)

Comment: Look into [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). (possible source of confusion : `^` does not have the same meaning when used as the first token of a character class (`[^...]`) than outside of a character class)

Comment: it is not what i expected CinCout :/

Comment: my input should accept any sentence like "blabla/blabla/blabla" but not a sentence started like "/blabla/blabla/bla". It must not start by a "/" at first character until the first letter of my directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do: `^[^\/]\S+$`

The regex checks that the first character is not a `'/'`, and then accepts every non-whitespace character till the end.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O9JGzg/1)

Comment: I just tested $scope.regex = "^[^\/]\S+$" on my client JS, and got ng-pattern="regex" on my angular input form, but it is still not working.

Comment: i got the ng-show error message pattern when i'm starting the sentence by a letter

Comment: i added $scope.regex = "^[^\/]\S+$"; on JS, and i got ng-pattern="regex" on my input with a span error ng-show="myFormName.directory.$error.pattern"

Comment: Check if you are adding `name="directory"` attribute on the field in question

Comment: `<input name="directory" id="directory" type="text" class="form-control" ng-pattern="regex" ng-model="directoryName" placeholder="Enter a directory name"/>` `<span class="error" ng-show="uploaderForm.directory.$error.pattern">a message</span>` That's what i got

Comment: Maybe there is some issue in the JS code, not sure though. The demo link runs the regex correctly.

Comment: Yup, the regex is correct.. hmm i dunno where i did a mistake cause i got all params u asked me .. and on JS side, i just assign the regex to a scope..

Comment: I am no JS expert, so I  asked for some basic stuff I know of. Maybe an expert will have more insights into the same.

Comment: I'd recommend you to ask another question posting your JS code and see what others have to suggest. This post won't draw any attention from JS experts since it is purely a regex based question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help anyway, ill waiting for an JS expert :) I should make this topic resolved, i got the regex, thanks guys.